# Could madgwick be a math error in the c # example?

Tags: imu, sensor-fusion

We gave the same input data to C# and Matlab examples. The values ​​on the quaternion outputs were different, although their inputs were the same. These examples can be downloaded from Madgwick website.
https://x-io.co.uk/open-source-imu-and-ahrs-algorithms/

[image]
Comparing Matlab and C#, we realized that, there're two missing *2 factor in C# code.

```
// Reference direction of Earth's magnetic field  
_2bx = (float)Math.Sqrt(hx * hx + hy * hy);   // 2* missing  
_2bz = -_2q1mx * q3 + _2q1my * q2 + mz * q1q1 + _2q2mx * q4 - mz * q2q2 + _2q3 * my * q4 - mz * q3q3 + mz * q4q4;   // 2* missing
```

After multiplying by 2 these lines, outputs overlap with each other.

[image]
I don't think much of Madgwick might not have noticed this, or did we think one point wrong? (They have videos using with C# example..)

Comment: Questions on stack exchange sites must stand on their own, in the sense that they must make sense *without* following any supplemental links.  Yours seems to rely heavily on an awareness of the content at your links.  Additionally, it seems like that you're running into an issue of defining the situation in which the code is supposed to operate, eg how it is supposed to be used.   Finally, this appears to be a pure software/algorithm issue and not directly related to embedded hardware at all - even if it's an embedded context, the question doesn't in any way depend on that.

Comment: I think you are right in some of the points you criticize. How can I close the question?Maybe there is a solution for people who have this problem, but this may not be the place for it.